# Nagios plugin to take process snapshot when load is high

Tags: linux, monitoring, nagios, performance-monitoring

We have configured `Nagios` with `check_load` via `NRPE` plugin to monitor server load, it reports when load is high, but does not have option to take a snapshot top processes (like `top` command) at that time.

Are there any `nagios` `NRPE` plug-ins for that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it with [event handlers](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/eventhandlers.html).

First, add an event handler for your Load average definition:

```
define service{
    use                     generic-service
    host_name               xx
    service_description     Load_Average
    check_command           check_nrpe!check_load
    event_handler           processes_snapshot!xx
    contact_groups          admin-sms
}
```

The `processes_snapshot` command is defined in `commands.cfg`:

```
define command{
    command_name    processes_snapshot
    command_line    $USER1$/eventhandlers/processes_snapshot.sh $SERVICESTATE$ $SERVICESTATETYPE$ $SERVICEATTEMPT$ $HOSTADDRESS$
}
```

And second, write an event handler script (`processes_snapshot.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
    OK)
        ;;
    WARNING)
        /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H $4 -c processes_snapshot
        ;;
    UNKNOWN)
        ;;
    CRITICAL)
        /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H $4 -c processes_snapshot
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

The command `processes_snapshot` is defined in `nrpe.cfg` on the `xx` host as belows:

```
command[processes_snapshot]=top -cSbn 1 | tail -n +8 | sort -rn -k11 | head > /tmp/proc_snap.txt
```

PS: I haven't tested this config.

Comment: This looks like it puts the snapshot in a file in /tmp.  Is it possible to get the list in the notification email that nagios sends?

Comment: There's a bug in the nrpe.cfg top command line: `-cSb n 1` should be `-cSbn 1`, otherwise you get `top: unknown argument 'n'`.

Comment: @MariusGedminas: 1. How do you send an email from the Nagios? Can you pipe the `top` output to `mail -s 'process snapshotting' youremail@domain.com`? 2. My `top` version on the CentOS, Gentoo, Ubuntu is working fine.

Comment: I use whatever the Debian package sets up by default.  I was hoping to see the process snapshot *in the same email* as the CRITICAL/WARNING notification; a separate one would be trivial to arrange, as you suggest.  The version of top that was complaining about the space in front of 'n' was from procps 1:3.2.8-11ubuntu6 (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS); top from procps 1:3.3.3-2ubuntu3 (Ubuntu 12.10) doesn't complain.

Comment: @MariusGedminas: there is some ways to do this: 1. Write your own plugin and append the `top` output to the `$SERVICEOUTPUT$`. 2. Define an additional command to send mail enclosed with `top` output and set it to the `service_notification_commands` in your contact.

Answer (score 8):

Here's what I did to get a process list snapshot **directly in the notification emails**, based on the idea by @quanta.  It may contain paths specific to the way Nagios is installed on Debian/Ubuntu machines:

1. Created a wrapper script `/usr/local/sbin/check_load` that calls the original and appends the process snapshot if the exit code is 1 (WARNING) or 2 (CRITICAL):

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_load "$@" || {
       rc=$?
       echo
       # http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/pluginapi.html
       # | separates long output from perfdata
       COLUMNS=1000 top -cSbn 1|sed -e 's/|/<BAR>/g' -e 's/ \+$//'
       exit $rc
   }
   ```

   This sets COLUMNS to a large number so the process names/command lines won't be truncated to 40 characters, run top in batch mode for one iteration (`-bn 1`), asks for full command lines (`-c`) and cumulative CPU times (`-S`) to be shown, then makes sure top's output isn't truncated at the first `|` character by replacing it with `<BAR>`.

   I find top's default sort order to be adequate -- attempting to re-sort by cumulative CPU time like was suggested in @quanta's answer puts system daemons like init or crond at the top, which doesn't help me figure out which CGI script was responsible for the CPU spike.  Also this way I get to keep top's header.

   Don't forget to `chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/check_load`
2. Edit `/etc/nagios-plugins/config/load.cfg` and replace the **check_load** entry

   ```
   command_line    /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_load --warning='$ARG1$,$ARG2$,$ARG3$' --critical='$ARG4$,$ARG5$,$ARG6$'
   ```

   with

   ```
   command_line    /usr/local/sbin/check_load --warning='$ARG1$,$ARG2$,$ARG3$' --critical='$ARG4$,$ARG5$,$ARG6$'
   ```
3. Edit `/etc/nagios3/commands.cfg` and update the **notify-service-by-email** entry so it includes $LONGSERVICEOUTPUT$ in the generated emails.  It's too long to paste here; basically find the `Info:\n\n$SERVICEOUTPUT$\n" | /usr/bin/mail` bit and change it to `Info:\n\n$SERVICEOUTPUT$\n$LONGSERVICEOUTPUT$\n" | /usr/bin/mail`.
4. Restart nagios: `service nagios3 restart`.

I haven't tried this with NRPE.

Comment: Works with nrpe too.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer:

```
command[processes_snapshot]=top -cSbn 1 | head -14 | tail -8
```