# How to check top processes?

Tags: command-line-interface

I'm look for shell script to send Top processes as an email when Monitor CPU load average exceed 20  I'm running RedHat 6.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/318588/nagios-plugin-to-take-process-snapshot-when-load-is-high

Answer (score 2):

```
uptime | awk '$NF >= 20 { system("top -cSb n 1") }' \
    | tail -n +8 | sort -rn -k11 | head \
        | mail -s "PROBLEM Service Alert: load_fifteen is CRITICAL" email@domain
```

- `NF` stands for Number of Fields. `$NF` get the value of the last
  field. This is the system load average for past 15 minutes
- `top -b` to run in batch mode, for sending output to stdout
- `tail -n +8 | sort -rn -k11 | head`: remove the headers, then sort by
  CPU Time, and get the top processes.